# React Passing Data From Child Component to Parent Component via a onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react and am currently working on a react rails application.

```
      <h1><img src={activity.image_url}/></h1>
          <p> {activity.name} </p>
          <p> Rating: {activity.rating} </p>
          <p><img src={activity.rating_img_url}/></p>
          <p>{activity.location.display_address.join(" ")}</p>
          <p><a href={activity.url}>Learn More</a></p>
          <input id="add_to" className="btn" type="submit" onClick={props.addto} value="Add to Profile"/>
```

Currently, this I am using `props.data.map((activity) => ...` to map over the data. My question is are there any ways I could somehow pass in the `.name, .rating, .url etc.` upon clicking the `"Add to Profile"` button (and store it into a variable for my parent component to use)? I have been looking all over for an answer but due to my lack of experience with react, I am struggling to find an answer I can understand.

I have also put a debugger in my top level component and it hits my debugger when I click the button "Add to Profile

```
handleAddTo(event) {
    debugger;
    event.preventDefault();
  }
```

I really would appreciate any help on this! Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using the `addTo` function from the props, I am assuming that is coming from the correct parent component and hence what you can do is just bind the values to this function like

```
<input id="add_to" className="btn" type="submit" onClick={props.addto.bind(this, activity.name, activity.rating, activity.rating_img_url)} value="Add to Profile"/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I did not know you could use .bind...(this.. /bind the values to your functions!

Comment: Did it solve your problem, Could you accept this as an answer if it helped

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass values you want in parents like

```
<input id="add_to" className="btn" type="submit" onClick={props.addto(activity.name, activity.rating, activity.rating_img_url)} value="Add to Profile"/>
```

and use it

```
handleAddTo(name, rating, imgUrl) {
 // do something with values
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much and thanks for expanding on my handleAddTo function! You both are awesome!